# How to identify UI corners entered on Drag and Drop UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop

I am doing UWP drag and drop to move child UI from one parent UI element to another parent UI element.
Using DragOver and Drop can do that. But it only start to listen if the touch/mouse pressed pointer enter.
It will not recognize if the dragging UI corner entered the UI element. Is there any way to identify dragging UI corner entered?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How to identify UI corners entered on Drag and Drop UWP?

I'm afraid you can't identify dragging UI corner entered. Because all the check pointers of drag and drop event are based on cursor's position. And it could easily detect if the cursor is over or not base on [`PointerMoved`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragover?view=winrt-18362#remarks) event. If you do want this feature please feel post your requirement with Windows Feed Back Hub app.

Comment: Exactly: as a matter of fact, when we select a file in File Explorer and then we start moving it on some other folder, only when the cursor enters the folder itself, the file can be ‘dropped’ on that folder. It’s a universal knowledge, to follow the cursor’s position.